# Write and retrieve files in Heroku and Dockerized fastAPI project

Tags: docker, heroku, fastapi

I'm struggling with this issue:
I've a fastAPI app with a couple of routes that are called by other services and I've to put up a testing environment for the customers to try out the features.

I've containerized the whole api project and it works very well.

Then I've published on Heroku via container stack the whole thing and now it doesn't save the files in the /response directory.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY ./src /app/src

RUN mkdir /app/responses

COPY ./requirements.txt /app
COPY ./start.sh /app
COPY ./templates /app/templates
COPY ./static /app/static


WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN chmod a+x ./start.sh
#EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

My fastAPI app has mounted the static file directory (which is not working either) and the responses directory as follows:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Request, Form
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, FileResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates


app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
app.mount("/responses", StaticFiles(directory="responses"), name="responses")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
```

And then I try to write the files with this code:

```
 filename = fiscalCode + "/" + fiscalCode +"_" +timestamp+".html"
    filepath = os.path.join(RESPONSE_FOLDER, filename)

    print(filepath)
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filepath), exist_ok=True)
        with open(filepath, "w+") as f:
            f.write(file.file.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

I know that Heroku filesystem is ephemeral but this is not an issue: the file must be available only for a couple of minutes for testing purposes.

I'm stuck bcs on other applications deployed via Heroku and Procfile (so without the Docker shenanigans) I had no issues at all in writing and retrieving files.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: What error message is Heroku giving you?

Answer (score 0):

I found that, even in Heroku remote shell, I can't see the files created, I think because of the ephemeral file system.

Nevertheless all the functions are working fine, and transitional files are stored somewhere in the hyperuranium.

So if you don't find your actual files, they are written on (I suppose) a caching memory or something like that.